# All errors in solution shown when project fails

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper

In Visual Studio 2015 community edition all the errors in the solution are shown even if they may not be errors.  Let's say I have a root project called Common and common fails to build.  Every project will be evaluated and every reference to an object in common will say

> "The type or namespace name 'xxx' does not exist in the namespace
>   'Common' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

This has a snowball effect as well, so any reference to any project object that didn't build is considered an error.  So in other words, in my 50 project solution where the first project doesn't build, I have 43183 Errors in the error list.  It hoses my system when I try to scroll and I can't find the *actual* error due to these false errors.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same behavior in Enterprise edition. Don't think it's related to the Community edition. I think this is by design.

Can you right click Common in Solution Explorer and just build that?

Comment: @BunnyStrider, if you close and re-open the solution, and then build just the one project, you should only see build errors from that project.